# JSplitPane divider drag not working with complex layout

Tags: java, swing, jsplitpane

I have a Java GUI program with a JSplitPane dividing the content. The left side of the JSplitPane is a JTabbedPane with a number of tabs - a very complex layout.  When the left side reaches a certain level of complexity, dragging the divider to move the divider location no longer works, but I can still move the divider by explicitly setting the location.  (If it matters, I am using Nimbus LAF.)

It doesn't seem to be just the number of tabs on the left.  Certain tabs that I include on the left make it stop working and others are OK.

Has anyone ever run into this?

I was able to work around it by adding a hack workaround method on my JSplitPane subclass.

```
    public void enableDividerWorkaround() {
      javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicSplitPaneUI l_ui = (javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicSplitPaneUI) getUI();
      BasicSplitPaneDivider l_divider = l_ui.getDivider();

      l_divider.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
          Dimension l_pane_size = getSize();
          if (getOrientation() == JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT) {
            int l_new_loc = getDividerLocation() + e.getX();
            if (l_new_loc >= 0 && l_new_loc <= l_pane_size.width) {
              setDividerLocation(l_new_loc);
            }
          } else {
            int l_new_loc = getDividerLocation() + e.getY();
            if (l_new_loc >= 0 && l_new_loc <= l_pane_size.height) {
              setDividerLocation(l_new_loc);
            }
          }
        }
      });
    }
```

UPDATE
Here is the SSCCE (below). When I run this, the first time I drag the slider to the right, it "snaps" to the end of the long label and then remains fixed there. I believe it is triggered by the long label.  If I shorten the label, I get more range of motion on the slider. So is it a bug, or the intended behavior?

```
    public class SplitPaneTest extends javax.swing.JFrame {
      public SplitPaneTest() {
        initComponents();
      }
      private void initComponents() {

        jSplitPane1 = new javax.swing.JSplitPane();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jSplitPane1.setDividerLocation(450);
        jSplitPane1.setName("jSplitPane1"); 

        jLabel1.setText("right side");
        jLabel1.setName("jLabel1"); 
        jSplitPane1.setRightComponent(jLabel1);

        jPanel1.setName("jPanel1"); 

        jLabel2.setText("left side asd adsf asdf asdf asdf sadf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdfa end");
        jLabel2.setName("jLabel2"); 

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
          jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
          .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jLabel2)
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
          jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
          .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jLabel2)
            .addContainerGap(420, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        jSplitPane1.setLeftComponent(jPanel1);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
          layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
          .addComponent(jSplitPane1)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
          layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
          .addComponent(jSplitPane1)
        );

        pack();
      }

      /**
       * @param args the command line arguments
       */
      public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
            new SplitPaneTest().setVisible(true);
          }
        });
      }
      protected javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
      protected javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
      protected javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
      protected javax.swing.JSplitPane jSplitPane1;
    }
```

Comment: An [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) would help out *IMMENSELY* here.

Comment: and SSCCE with description for why reason in there added MouseMotionListener

Comment: please is there definition for SplitPaneUI too

Comment: I spent quite a bit of time trying to get to the point of having a SSCCE but was unable to do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be intentional behavior.  Found the following code in the constructor of javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicSplitPaneDivider.DragController:

```
minX = leftC.getMinimumSize().width;
```

then later on in that same class

```
    /**
    * Returns the new position to put the divider at based on
    * the passed in MouseEvent.
    */
    protected int positionForMouseEvent(MouseEvent e) {
      int newX = (e.getSource() == BasicSplitPaneDivider.this) ?
                  (e.getX() + getLocation().x) : e.getX();

      newX = Math.min(maxX, Math.max(minX, newX - offset));
      return newX;
    }
```

So it appears that the basic UI intentionally doesn't let you drag the divider in such a way as to make the left side smaller than its minimum size.

In my case, that behavior doesn't fit my needs, so my little workaround is necessary.

Answer (score 3):

> I spent quite a bit of time trying to get to the point of having a
>   SSCCE but was unable to do so

.

- please what??? an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) up to 5minutes

  ---
- now there are still two questions

  1. is there definition for `SplitPaneUI` too, because `if (ui instanceof BasicSplitPaneUI) {` can returns pretty the `false`
  2. with description for why reason in there added MouseMotionListener

---

EDIT_1st.

> The left side of the JSplitPane is a JTabbedPane with a number of tabs
>   - a very complex layout. When the left side reaches a certain level of complexity, dragging the divider to move the divider location no
>   longer works, but I can still move the divider by explicitly setting
>   the location.

- [wild shot in the dark == you need to know](http://exampledepot.8waytrips.com/egs/javax.swing/split_SpWeight.html)

> Distributing Space When a JSplitPane Container Is Resized The weight
>   of a split pane controls the behavior of the divider when the split
>   pane is resized. If the weight is 0, all extra space is given to the
>   right or bottom component. If the weight is 1, all extra space is
>   given to the left or top component. A weight of .3 specifies that the
>   left or top component gets one-third of the extra space. The weight
>   also determines how the children lose space when the size of the split
>   pane is reduced. For example, a weight of 0 means that the left or top
>   component does not lose any space.
>
> The weight also controls the starting location of the divider. For
>   example, if the weight is .5, the divider is placed in the center.
>   COPY

```
// Create a left-right split pane
JSplitPane pane = new JSplitPane(
     JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT, leftComponent, rightComponent);

// Get current weight
double weight = pane.getResizeWeight();    // 0.0 by default

// Keep the size of the right component constant
weight = 1D;
pane.setResizeWeight(weight);

// Split the space evenly
weight = .5D;
pane.setResizeWeight(weight);
```

---

EDIT_2nd.

you forgot to tell us that in Nimbus is there awfull flickering with divider, not caused with rest of Standard L&Fs

---

[image]

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JSplitPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicSplitPaneDivider;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicSplitPaneUI;

public class JSplitPaneToy {

    private JSplitPane sp;

    public JSplitPaneToy() {
        sp = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT, makePanel(), makePanel());
        /*SplitPaneUI ui = sp.getUI();
         if (ui instanceof BasicSplitPaneUI) {
         ((BasicSplitPaneUI) ui).getDivider().setBorder(null);
         }*/
        BasicSplitPaneUI l_ui = (BasicSplitPaneUI) sp.getUI();
        BasicSplitPaneDivider l_divider = l_ui.getDivider();
        l_divider.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                Dimension l_pane_size = sp.getSize();
                if (sp.getOrientation() == JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT) {
                    int l_new_loc = sp.getDividerLocation() + e.getX();
                    if (l_new_loc >= 0 && l_new_loc <= l_pane_size.width) {
                        sp.setDividerLocation(l_new_loc);
                    }
                } else {
                    int l_new_loc = sp.getDividerLocation() + e.getY();
                    if (l_new_loc >= 0 && l_new_loc <= l_pane_size.height) {
                        sp.setDividerLocation(l_new_loc);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        sp.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
        /*sp = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT, makePanel(), sp);
         ui = sp.getUI();
         if (ui instanceof BasicSplitPaneUI) {
         ((BasicSplitPaneUI) ui).getDivider().setBorder(null);
         }
         sp.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
         sp = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT, makePanel(), sp);
         ui = sp.getUI();
         if (ui instanceof BasicSplitPaneUI) {
         ((BasicSplitPaneUI) ui).getDivider().setBorder(null);
         }
         sp.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
         sp = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT, makePanel(), sp);
         ui = sp.getUI();
         if (ui instanceof BasicSplitPaneUI) {
         ((BasicSplitPaneUI) ui).getDivider().setBorder(null);
         }
         sp.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());*/
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("JSplitPane Toy");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setContentPane(sp);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new JSplitPaneToy();
            }
        });
    }

    private JScrollPane makePanel() {
        JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(new JTable(
                new Object[][]{{0, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 4}}, new Object[]{1, 2, 3}) {
        });
        pane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 100));
        return pane;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think the resize weight applies here - the JSplitPane is not being resized, just the divider is being moved. 

I'll take another shot at a SSCCE.  I thought of a different approach to get there that might work.